# DocuSign API test demo - Faild to login demo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, docusignapi

I try run the c# Hello world sample in visual studio - I'm jost trying the free DSA demo.

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes/blob/master/dsa-rest/Hello-World-examples/DSARestCsharpSample/Program.cs

I don't know if the parameters of :
`dsa-user-password`
`dsa-user-name`

When I change them to my username and password (username = email address??)
the response content is :

> "Message: "Failed to login, check username, password and domain.",
>   "Module":"SAPIWS", "Code":-20, "InnerCode":-1878916813

maybe also need to change :

`baseURL`
`resourcePath`

What data should I put ??

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you want to run the DocuSign API test demo successfully.

I suggest that you register a new DSA account, it is not recommended to use the test account.

Registration link: https://go.docusign.com/signup/dsa-developer/

You can try the following code：

Note:`//D:\\work\\PurchaseOrder.pdf is a self-created pdf`

```
//D:\\work\\PurchaseOrder.DSA-REST-SIGNED.pdf code is generated pdf
```

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        String baseURL = "https://prime-dsa-devctr.docusign.net:8081";
        String resourcePath = "sapiws/v1/digital_signature";
        String apiUrl = baseURL + "/" + resourcePath;
        var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");           
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + DSABasicAuthorizationString("Vtestdemo1@hotmail.com", "testpwd12"));
        // "digital_signature" request body as Json formated String (use JavaScriptSerializer or Newtonsoft.Json to build from object) 
        String DigSigRequestBody =
            "{ \"CreateAndSignField\" : " + //structure name specifies the operation / function
                "{   \"file\": " + "\"" + File2Base64String("D:\\work\\PurchaseOrder.pdf") + "\", " +
                    "\"fileType\": \"PDF\", " +
                    "\"x\": \"91\", " +
                    "\"y\": \"164\", " +
                    "\"width\": \"113\", " +
                    "\"height\": \"38\", " +
                    "\"page\": \"1\", " +
                    "\"timeFormat\": \"h:mm:ss\", " +
                    "\"dateFormat\": \"dd/MM/yyyy\", " +
                    "\"appearance\": [\"GRAPHICAL_IMAGE\", \"SIGNED_BY\", \"TIME\"]" +
                "}" +
            "}";
        request.AddParameter("application/json", DigSigRequestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

        Base64String2Path(joResponse["signedFile"].Value<string>(), "D:\\work\\PurchaseOrder.DSA-REST-SIGNED.pdf");
        Console.WriteLine("success");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Base64String2Path(string Base64String, string FilePath)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);
        File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, bytes);
    }

    private static String File2Base64String(String FilePath)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
        String fileB64Data = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        return fileB64Data;
    }

    private static String DSABasicAuthorizationString(String username, string password)
    {
        var DSABasicAuthorizationBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(DSABasicAuthorizationBytes);
    }
```

Pdf file link:https://github.com/docusign/docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes/blob/master/dsa-rest/Hello-World-examples/PurchaceOrder.pdf

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a DSA sandbox account. See https://developers.docusign.com/dsa-api to signup.

Also, are you sure you want to be using the DocuSign Signing Appliance? It is an on-premises hardware digital signing solution.

Most use cases use the DocuSign cloud eSignature service. It has different APIs. See the [Developer Center](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api).

Comment: Thanks!
Another question: Do you know by what signature standard?
I need a signature by standard-  Certificate X.509 (IETF PKIX) RFC 3647
Do I have to purchase the certificate separately or is it included in DSA?

Comment: Re source of the X.509 certificates. We have many many options for the certificates. The DSA includes a an optional certificate authority, so it can create certificates for you. Those certificates, if you wish, can be chained to your own corp master cert. We can also supply you with qualified certificates on the fly, or you can bring your own qualified certificates. Talk to our digital signature experts.